# Deploy Apollo Server to IIS

Tags: iis, graphql, apollo-server, iisnode

I am trying to deploy my GraphQL server to IIS (not sure if this is the best way to do this) using IISNode.

I've used the following guides but still can't seem to get it going:

[Installing IISNode](https://harveywilliams.net/blog/installing-iisnode)

[Deploying GraphQL Express](https://ayerdi.tech/deploy-graphql-express-server-on-windows-using-iisnode/)

[Official IISNode Docs](https://github.com/Azure/iisnode)

Would anyone have any step by step instructions on how to do this, or maybe a different route I could take all together to host my GraphQL server?

The end goal is to be able to access the GraphQL Playground from any device connected to a local network by doing something like this on the devices browser app:

http://ip-of-server-hosting-graphql/graphql

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use iis reverse proxy module to the server the express js app from iis.

for that first you need to install URL rewrite and Application Request Routing extension in iis:

[URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

[Application Request Routing](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing)

- now open iis and select any site.
- double click on URL rewrite from the middle pane.

[image]

- Add a new rule and select the Reverse Proxy template.

[image]

- Enable proxy functionality when you are prompted for it.

[image]

- Add the address of your node.js website, don't forget to include the port, to the reverse proxy rules.

[image]

- Once the rule has been added, the reverse proxy configuration works.

[image]

to keep running you node js app you could install pm2:

```
npm install -g pm2
```

`pm2 start app.js`: start our Node.js application

`pm2 stop`: stop a running process

`pm2 restart`: restart a running process

`pm2 list`: list all running processes

reference links:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world/ba-p/846222

https://dev.to/petereysermans/hosting-a-node-js-application-on-windows-with-iis-as-reverse-proxy-397b

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I tried your suggestion but it didnt work.I created a new site, set the physical path to the path of my application, followed the steps you provided to create a rule, but I am still not able to get to the website.

Comment: @AmericoPerez what issue did you face when you try to access the site? do you able to run the site locally with a reverse proxy?